# How can I address a script I don't know the type of?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

My game uses a variety of different game modes, and I'd like to spawn a different GameController script at the beginning of the scene depending on the game mode selected. Then other items (e.g., Enemies), would reference the main GameController, whether that be GameController_Mode1, GameController_Mode2, etc. But how can I have other objects referencing this if I don't know the type?

Unity iOS requires strict unityscript typing, so I can't use duck typing to get around this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this the same way you'd do it in C#, [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).  Derive all of your controllers from a single base Controller class.  Then your GameController `var` can be set to any instantiation of a derived controller (see `Start()` in the example below).

Here is a quick example using a simple controller:

```
#pragma strict

var controller : MyController;

class MyController  {
var data : int;
public function MyController(){
    this.data = 42;
}
public function Print(){
    Debug.Log("Controller: " + this.data);
}
}
class MyController1 extends MyController {
public function MyController1(){
    this.data = 43;
}
public function Print(){
    Debug.Log("Controller1: " + this.data);
}
}
class MyController2 extends MyController {
public function MyController2(){
    this.data = 44;
}
public function Print(){
    Debug.Log("Controller2: " + this.data);
}
}

function Start () {
controller = new MyController();
controller.Print(); // prints Controller: 42

controller = new MyController1();
controller.Print(); // prints Controller1: 43

controller = new MyController2();
controller.Print(); // prints Controller2: 44
}
```

I'm making any assumption that your gamecontrollers share function names and that the only difference is the code in each function.

**[Update]**

Regarding Heisenbug's comment below:  You can use GetComponent to get the base class controller if your controller is a component.

Baseclass(BaseController.js):

```
class BaseController extends MonoBehaviour{
    public function Print(){
        Debug.Log("BaseController");
    }
}
```

Extended class(Controller1.js):

```
class Controller1 extends BaseController {
    public function Print(){
        Debug.Log("Controller1: " + this.data);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
var controller : BaseController;
controller = gameObject.GetComponent("BaseController"); //.GetComponent(BaseController) also works
controller.Print(); // will print "Controller1" if actual attached component is a Controller1 type
```

Comment: @Heisenbug When you say it's still difficult to access a base class from another script, did you mean another GameObject?  Because I can easily move my base class to a separate script file and it works as expected.

Comment: WOW! This works perfectly. Thanks very much Jerdak.

I am not very experienced using the 'extends' keyword. I've tried reading up on it but am I right in thinking it means it is the base class + extended class (adding any additional code to the base class)? Or can the extended class **only** use variables and functions that exist in the base class?

Either way, this is pretty powerful. I love this site! :)

Comment: @Essential The subclass (extended class) can define whatever variables and functions it likes but you can't call those directly unless you know which subclass you are pointing to and that's a whole other question.

Answer (score 1):

While it looks like there are some good answers already but it is worth mentioning Unity's SendMessage system. It is a really simple approach if all you need to do is call functions on the other object SendMessage.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html

In short you can use the following syntax:

```
TargetGameObject.SendMessage("targetFunction", argument, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
```

You can also use SendMessage to call javascript functions from C# scripts or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks Luke, I didn't think of SendMessage(). Would be a simple option, although I believe apparently slower in performance than Jerdak's method.

Comment: Jerdak's solution is going to perform better for sure, but for quick stuff SendMessage() is pretty awesome.