# Calling member functions of dynamic objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following code.

```
GameObject target;
dynamic script;
script = target.GetComponent("ScriptName");
script.changeState();
```

Although I am using unity3d tool for game development, I feel this relates more to a generic c# question. In the code, I am obtaining an object which is the script linked to another gameobject. My aim is to call the changeState() function of the script belonging to 'target'. This gives an error since it cannot determine whether changeState() belongs to the dynamic variable 'script'. Is there any option to turn this off(analogous to #define pragma strict)? Is there any other workaround?

Note: Script attached to a GameObject referred by this script has an implementation of changeState() function.

Comment: can you add full error text?

Comment: @GuruStron Internal compiler error. See the console log for more information. output was:error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite' is not defined or imported

Comment: it's compile time error: [Compiler Error CS0518](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5c3ehka(v=vs.110).aspx). It can't be caused by `script` lacking any method because it resolves at run-time

Comment: @GuruStron I remove the piece of code I mentioned and there is no error in my program.

Comment: This question seems useless.  The form of GetComponent you're using suggests that you are using dynamic because you don't know what you're doing.  Can you explain why that might not be true?

Comment: Okay. Here is the scenario:
A Switch is used to control many types of gameObjects. So, instead of making n scripts for the switch controlling n types of gameObjects I have created one switch script which can control any type of gameObject. Hence, I do not know the name of the script beforehand and thus the problem arises.(and I have solved it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using an interface here since all your potential scripts you can swap out contain the method changeState() tie them to an interface to express that.

This gives you a bit more type safety and better re-factoring rather than using magic strings. It also gives you a good error checking point when you cast it.

```
GameObject target;
InterfaceType script;
script = target.GetComponent("ScriptName") as InterfaceType;

if(script != null)
{
    script.changeState();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Internal compiler error. See the console log for more information. output was:error CS0518: The predefined type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite' is not defined or imported.`

Are you referencing System.Core.dll?

[Compiler Error CS0518](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5c3ehka%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: yeah mscorlib.dll is present in references. I think this has more to do with the use of dynamic, which I am unable to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Anyway, I found the solution and I have posted it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with GameObject, but maybe you can do something like:

```
GameObject target;
var script = target.GetComponent("ScriptName") as GameObject;
if (script != null)
{
    script.changeState();
}
```

Comment: The 'as' keyword is used only for strict typing. Besides the GetComponent() retrieves UnityEngine.Component. If 'as GameObject' is used, then UnityEngine.GameObject is retrieved. So, the above code can't work.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html):

```
var script = gameObject.GetComponent(FooTest); //note the lack of quotes
script.FooTestMethod();  //and method unique to FooTest
```

If the component doesn't exist, Unity will complain.

If you really insist on using the string based `GetComponent`:

```
var script = gameObject.GetComponent("FooTest") as FooTest;
script.FooTestMethod();
```

Comment: I don't think you understand my question clearly. The problem is I do not know the type of script attached to my gameobject 'target'. 'target' can be any gameobject, which I drag and drop to this script's Gameobject field in the GUI. So, I cannot use GetComponent(FooTest) since it is specific to FooTest script, which is attached to just one gameobject. If I want to drag and drop another gameobject, then I'll have to change that line every time I drag a different object.

Comment: See my solution below and you'll understand what I wanted exactly.

Comment: @user854617 'ScriptName' is not a variable name, it's the name of an attached MonoBehaviour component.  If you know already `ScriptName` then you already know the component type and there is no need for a member invocation.

Comment: In your code:

`var script = gameObject.GetComponent("FooTest") as FooTest;
script.FooTestMethod();`

Suppose I want to change the part where 'script' is typecasted to FooTest(after the 'as' keyword) to some other script's name during runtime, how do I do it?

Comment: [You use polymorphism](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765211/how-can-i-address-a-script-i-dont-know-the-type-of/16766584#16766584) and create a parent class with `ChangeState()`.  I'm not saying your answer doesn't work, I'm trying to point out that there are much easier (and more efficient) ways of calling the same method on multiple components.

Comment: But in unity3d , every script must be a child of MonoBehavior. The polymorphism approach cannot be used here, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

So here is the solution to my own problem. Instead of dynamic type one can use 'object' type. Here is my code:

```
object script = target.GetComponent("ScriptName");
Type scriptType = script.GetType();
object res = scriptType.InvokeMember("changeState", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
  null, script, null);
```

The InvokeMember() does not resolve the member functions of the object type during compile time. Don't forget to include 'System.Reflection'.Hope this helps someone.