# BCE0019: 'collision' is not a member of 'Object'

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Thats Unity3D js script error, on pc it work fine, but if I try to switch platform to android...

Trigger_Script :

```
#pragma strict
var P : GameObject;
var P_script;
var P_objname = "Player";
var P_script_name = "Player_script";

function Start() {

P = GameObject.Find(P_objname);
P_script = P.GetComponent(P_script_name);
}

function OnTriggerEnter(collider : Collider) {
if(collider.gameObject.name == P_objname) P_script.collision = true;
}
```

And The Player_Script :

```
#pragma strict
var collision : boolean;
var respawn_position : Vector3;
var respawn_time : int = 1;
var respawn_objname = "Respawn";

function Update () {
if(collision) {
Respawn();
}
    }

function Respawn() {
renderer.enabled = false;
respawn_position = GameObject.Find(respawn_objname).transform.position;
gameObject.transform.position = respawn_position;
yield WaitForSeconds(respawn_time);
renderer.enabled = true;
collision = false;
}
```

Help Me Plz :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the type of `P_script` ahead of time, you should use [SendMessage](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html) or you'll want to use [polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765211/how-can-i-address-a-script-i-dont-know-the-type-of/16766584#16766584).

If you know the script type ahead of time:

```
#pragma strict
var P_script : YourScript;


function Start() {
    var tmp = GameObject.Find(P_objname);
    P_script = tmp.GetComponent("YourScript");
    P_script.collision = true;
    Debug.Log("Current collision: " + P_script.collision);
}
```

If you **don't** know the script type ahead of time:

```
//(Trigger script)
#pragma strict
var P_script : YourScript;


function Start() {
    var tmp = GameObject.Find(P_objname);
    tmp.SendMessage("SetCollision",true);

    P_script = tmp.GetComponent("YourScript");
    Debug.Log("Current collision: " + P_script.collision);
}

//(Player script)
//... all your other code plus this:
function SetCollision(var b : boolean){
    collision = b;
}
```

Comment: I have test this, but now : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Trigger_script.Start () (at Assets/Script/Trigger_script.js:8)

#pragma strict

var P_script : Player_script;

var P_objname = "Player";


function Start() {

    var tmp = GameObject.Find(P_objname);

    P_script = tmp.GetComponent("Player_script");

    P_script.collision = true;

    Debug.Log("Current collision: " + P_script.collision);

}

Comment: @RaffaeleElShaarawyIabichino `tmp.GetComponent("Player_script");` must *exactly* match the name of your script.  Try using `tmp.GetComponent("Player_Script");` (note the capital 'S')

Comment: Ok i Try, and : NullReferenceException
Player_script+$Respawn$34+$.MoveNext () (at Assets/Script/Player_script.js:23)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine_Auto(IEnumerator)
Player_script:Update() (at Assets/Script/Player_script.js:13), And another ERROR : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Trigger_script.Start () (at Assets/Script/Trigger_script.js:9). LoL Now ? Help meee....